# Calculating Runtime

Tags: runtime, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck on the following problem I was able to solve the first part, however, I'm not sure how to proceed from there:

**how many times does the following program print out "Hi"? That is, what is the running time? (in terms of Big-O notation)**

```
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
while(i <= n )
{
    j+= j;
   int k = 1;
   while (k <= j)
    {
       System.out.println("Hi");
       k = k +1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

I was able to deduce that the program would produce *Summation from x = 1 to n* (2^x) amount of Hi's. Is this also the run time or should I break the code down into two summations where one is from i = 1to n and the other is ....(I don't know). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your runtime as a summation looks correct. So then the question is how you simplify it. Fortunately, we have this fact:

> 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + ... + 2<sup>n-1</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1.

Ignoring any off-by-one errors in substituting this sum for your sum, which we can do thanks to big-O notation, we see that “Hello!” gets printed out Θ(2<sup>n</sup>) times.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can try like this

```
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    while(i <= n )
    {
        j+= j;
       int k = 1;
       while (k <= j)
        {
           System.out.println("Hi");
           k = k +1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("time taken in nano seconds" + endTime-startTime);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, the question would want in the form of a Big-O notation. I added that edit to my question.